# How to get the values of an asp.net user control with two textboxes with same id in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

searched a lot but couldn't get anywhere..My case : I have a UserControl called DateControl:

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="ValueDateTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm nepali-datepicker ignore" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" />
</div>
```

It has got one textbox which i am using for datepicker. In my .aspx page i am used the control like this :

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
                                From Date
                            </label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <uc1:DateControl runat="server" ID="FromDateControl" />
  </div>

  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
                                To Date
                            </label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <uc1:DateControl runat="server" ID="ToDateControl" />
  </div>
</div>
<small class="col-sm-offset-2 text-warning pvInfo"></small>
```

In my case i have to select two dates FROM and TO from the datepicker.There is no problem to access the dates from server side since i can access it like

```js
var fromDate = FromDateControl.ValueDateAd;
var toDate = ToDateControl.ValueDateAd;
```

And this gets me the selected date.But in my case again here i need to pass these two dates to an ajax call.And since both the datepicker id's is
**ValueDateTextBox**,i am getting both the selected date same.

**JS Code**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ShowInGridButton').on('click',
            function () {
                
                var accountNumberId = $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val();
             
                var fromDateCtrl = $('[id$="FromDateControl"]').find('[id$="ValueDateTextBox"]');
                alert(fromDateCtrl.val());
                var toDateCtrl = $('[id$="ToDateControl"]').find('[id$="ValueDateTextBox"]');
                alert(toDateCtrl.val());

                //var fromDate = $('#ValueDateTextBox').val();
               
                //var toDate = $('#ValueDateTextBox').val();
                var url = "/WebMethods/Deposit.asmx/GetDepositAccountStatement";
                var d = { accountNumberId: accountNumberId, fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate };
                var jqXhr = ajaxPost(url, d);
                jqXhr.done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data) {
                        var div = $('#CfDataTable').empty();
                        div.append(
                           $("<tr class='success'><th>Tran Date</th><th>Value Date</th><th>Statement Reference</th><th>Check No.</th><th>Collector</th><th>Debit</th><th>Credit</th><th>Balance</th></tr>"));
                      
                        $(data.d).each(function (index, item) {

                            div.append(
                                    $("<tr>")

                                    .append($("<td>").html(ToJavaScriptDate(item.TranDate)))
                                    .append($("<td>").html(ToJavaScriptDate(item.ValueDate)))
                                    //.append($("<td>").html(item.TranDate))
                                    //.append($("<td>").html(item.ValueDate))
                                    .append($("<td>").html(item.StatementReference))
                                    .append($("<td>").html(item.CheckNumber))
                                    .append($("<td>").html(item.Collector))
                                    .append($("<td>").html(item.Debit))
                                    .append($("<td>").html(item.Credit))
                                    .append($("<td>").html(item.Balance)));


                        });
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log('Data Retrieve failed.');
                });
            });
    });
```

So its obvious here that being same ids the value would be same.I even tried doing this looking around here

```js
var bothElements = document.querySelectorAll("[id='ValueDateTextBox']");
var first = bothElements[0];
alert(first);
```

Still couldnt get the different date for the selected date from the date picker.Help appreciated.Thanks.It isnt that i didnt looked around for possible solutions,had to ask here.sorry if too vague a question for you expert devs.:)

**Edited**

Code behind of DateControl

```
 public partial class DateControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string ValueDateNp
    {
        get { return ValueDateTextBox.Text; }
        set { ValueDateTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
    public DateTime ValueDateAd
    {
        get { return DateConversion.GetEnglishDate(ValueDateTextBox.Text).ToDateTime(); }
        set
        {
            if (value == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                ValueDateTextBox.Text = DateConversion.GetCurrentBSServerDate();
            }
            ValueDateTextBox.Text = DateConversion.GetNepaliDate(value);
        }
    }

    public bool IsDateDisabled { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ValueDateTextBox.Text = DateConversion.GetCurrentBSServerDate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ValueDateTextBox.Focus();
        }
        if (IsDateDisabled)
        {
            ValueDateTextBox.MakeReadOnly();
            ValueDateTextBox.CssClass.Remove(3);
        }
    }

    public void BindDataProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
    {
        ValueDateTextBox.SetDataBindPropertyName(property);
    }



}
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**. Use a class instead of an id.

Comment: @Andreas Hello sir..even if i use class,since there is a single ValueDateTextBox, how do i get the two different selected values?Thanks

Comment: if you use JS to select the elements by a given class, you'll get both textboxes returned in an array, and you can loop through the array to find the individual values.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you sire.Mind giving me an example for my case.A small snippet would be helpful.I am new to Js.This isnt a code mill i know but a small help is appreciated.:)

Comment: `var dates = $(".datepicker");` gets you the fields (assuming they have a class "datepicker" shared across both textboxes). Then, using jQuery, you can use the .each() method to loop over them. https://api.jquery.com/each/ . Rough example: `dates.each(function() {
    alert( this.value);
  });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a parent container with id(`FromDateControl` & `ToDateControl`), you can use them to find the inner child.

```
var fromDateCtrl = $('[id$="FromDateControl"]').find('[id$="ValueDateTextBox"]');
alert(fromDateCtrl.val());
```

Comment: check `alert($('[id$="FromDateControl"]').length)`

Comment: Getting 0 now sir

Comment: Instead of finding a workaround, just use valid markup and replace the id with a class

Comment: @oldmonk ok, then your scripts might be running before the html. Are you running scripts on document ready?

Comment: @Andreas you mean this class '.form-control input-sm nepali-datepicker ignore'

Comment: @Bharadwaj sir..i am new to js..but no..the scripts isnt running on $(document).ready(function()

Comment: @oldmonk welcome to web development, when coding in js and jq, you have to make sure that the scripts which are trying to find some element should always run after that element is loaded. There is some other way to find the dynamic elements as soon as they added, but that is different. You can add your code at the end of the file or you can wrap it inside document ready event.

Comment: @Bharadwaj i have edited my question and added the js code..can you check that sir..and thanks.:)

Comment: @oldmonk inside `find()` try by replacing `$` with `*`.
 (`find('[id*="ValueDateTextBox"]')`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160427/discussion-between-bharadwaj-and-oldmonk).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bharadwaj sir.You were godsend.:)